# How to convert "WITH" clause MS SQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to display products categories like this way;

```
Table Name: PSCategories

PSId      | PSName         | ParentId(FK to PSCategories(PSId) )
1         | test1          | NULL
2         | test2          | 1
3         | test3          | NULL
4         | test4          | 3
5         | test5          | 4
```

This table data I want to filter in this way

```
PSId     | PSName                  | ParentId
1        | test1                   | 0
2        | test1 > test2           | 1
3        | test3                   | 0
4        | test3 > test4           | 3
5        | test3 > test4 > test5   | 4
```

**This mssql query can do it, but how to convert it to mysql**

```
WITH categories (PSId, PSName, ParentId)
  AS (SELECT PSId, CAST(PSName AS VARCHAR(255)), 0
        FROM PSCategories AS pm
       WHERE pm.ParentId IS NULL
       UNION ALL
      SELECT ps.PSId, CAST(m.PSName + ' > ' + ps.PSName AS VARCHAR(255)), m.PSId
        FROM PSCategories AS ps
        JOIN categories AS m
          ON m.PSId = ps.ParentId
       WHERE ps.ParentId IS NOT NULL
       )
SELECT * FROM categories
ORDER BY PSId
```

Comment: copy and paste it as a subquery...

Comment: This is a recursive CTE, c&p won't work here

Comment: @MartinK.: Where is the recursion?

Comment: @gexicide : `ON m.PSId = ps.ParentId`

Comment: This cannot be converted to MySQL because MySQL does not support recursive queries. You need to write a stored procedure. Search for "mysql recursive query" here or using google.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, MySQL does not support recursion (nor CTEs).

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but the something_UID, something_parent_UID pattern is almost always an antipattern.

Closure tables are much better (and simpler and faster to query) than recursion.

So you should store your hierarchy information in a closure-table.
See here: 
http://dirtsimple.org/2010/11/simplest-way-to-do-tree-based-queries.html
and here:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/14/moving-subtrees-in-closure-table/

The closure table also has the advantage that it works on MySQL, where CTE & recursion are not supported.

Comment: I disagree that the adjacency model is "*almost always an antipattern*". For modern DBMS that do support recursion this is usually very efficient and much easier to maintain than a closure table. For a read-only hierarchy a closure table might be acceptable, but not when the hierarchy changes often.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, closure tables are more difficult to understand.  But why should hierarchy change often ? And why should that be a problem with closure tables ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Additionally, SQL-Server doesn't support delete cascade on self-references.